# spinner values not displaying in android

Tags: php, android

Hi In This code first two values showing data and from third string array it giving null pointer Exception but data coming from database.can any one please help me.

This values only showing NullPointerException

```
patient_main_type_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("patient_main_type_name");
patient_type_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("patient_type_name");
religion_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("religion_name");
caste_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("caste_name");
```

**class file**

```
String result = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("getpatient","");
System.out.print(result);

try
{
    JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);

    initial_name = new String[JA.length()];
    initial_id = new String[JA.length()];
    patient_main_type_name = new String[JA.length()];
    patient_type_name = new String[JA.length()];
    religion_name= new String[JA.length()];
    caste_name= new String[JA.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
    {
        initial_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("initial_name");
        initial_id[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("initial_id");
        patient_main_type_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("patient_main_type_name");
        patient_type_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("patient_type_name");
        religion_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("religion_name");
        caste_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("caste_name");
    }

    spinner_fn();  
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
}
private void spinner_fn() {

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                initial_name);
        dataAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        intial.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        intial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", initial_name[position]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                patient_main_type_name);
        dataAdapter1
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        pmaincat.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

        pmaincat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.e("Position new", patient_main_type_name[position]);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
```

**logcat**

```
10-31 10:08:23.045: E/Fail 3(7235): java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
10-31 10:08:23.045: E/Fail 3(7235): org.json.JSONException: No value for patient_main_type_name
10-31 10:08:23.054: E/Fail 3(7235): org.json.JSONException: No value for patient_type_name
```

**json data**

```
[{"initial_id":"1","initial_name":"Mr.","sex":"male","to_patient":"1","to_employee":"1"},{"initial_id":"2","initial_name":"Mrs.","sex":"female","to_patient":"1","to_employee":"1"},{"initial_id":"3","initial_name":"","sex":"male","to_patient":"1","to_employee":"1"}]       [{"patient_main_type_id":"36","patient_main_type_name":"asdasdsa","billing_type":"TPA"},{"patient_main_type_id":"37","patient_main_type_name":"sasa","billing_type":"TPA"},{"patient_main_type_id":"85","patient_main_type_name":"awsome","billing_type":"CGHS"},{"patient_main_type_id":"86","patient_main_type_name":"ssssssssss","billing_type":"CGHS"},{"patient_main_type_id":"87","patient_main_type_name":"ddddddd","billing_type":"TPA"}]           [{"patient_type_id":"1","patient_type_name":"abc","patient_main_type_id":"36"},{"patient_type_id":"2","patient_type_name":"pqr","patient_main_type_id":"36"},{"patient_type_id":"3","patient_type_name":"lmn","patient_main_type_id":"85"}]
```

Comment: Post your logcat then,.....

Comment: Hi posted my logcat error

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Paste here and check it http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/

Comment: it showing i error how to know that error